# SQL Server XQuery not working with .nodes()

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

Given the followng xml doc, stored in an xml column called OfficersXML:

```
<Officers xmlns="urn:reuterscompanycontent:officersdirectors03" Major="3" Minor="0" Revision="2" lang="en-US">
  <RepNo>0004N</RepNo>
  <CompanyName Type="Primary">Alpharma Inc.</CompanyName>
</Officers>
```

Why does the following return 0 rows?

```
SELECT tbl.col.value(N'(./CompanyName)[1]',N'nvarchar(4000)') 
FROM dbo.RawData rd
CROSS APPLY OfficersXML.nodes(N'/Officers') tbl(col)
```

Comment: Have you tried the individual pieces?  Like just a select out of OfficerXML to make sure your cross-apply is giving something?  And a separate query to make sure your tbl.col.value(N'.... syntax is grabbing what you think it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT tbl.col.value(N'(*:CompanyName)[1]',N'nvarchar(4000)') 
FROM dbo.RawData rd
CROSS APPLY OfficersXML.nodes(N'/*:Officers') tbl(col)
```

You can also use the with namespace set to a default namespace:
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'urn:reuterscompanycontent:officersdirectors03')

More Info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177607.aspx